# What datatype should I use for software version in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to store software version in mysql for the following:

- examples:

  ```
  1.0.5, 
  1.0.6-beta, 
  3.1.3, 
  4.0,         
  etc
  ```
- usages:

  ```
  to find the latest, 
  to find all item whose version is higher than 2.5
  ```

What datatype should I use for this?

Comment: If there's duplicate questions, please let me know.  I googled but had no luck.

Comment: you better keep the releaded timestamp along with the version for aggregation purposes.